# POST request giving empty results

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, web-scraping

I've written some code in python using POST request to fetch specific data from a webpage. However, when I run it, I get nothing as result except for a blank console. I've tried to fill in the request parameter accordingly. Perhaps, I can't notice which should be included in the parameter. The page I'm dealing with contains several images in it's right panel. When an image is clicked the request about which i'm talking here is sent to the server and brings back the result and displays new information concerning its' flavor under it. My goal is to parse all the flavors connected to each images. Anyways, I'm trying to attach all the things necessary to find out what i'm missing. Thanks in advance.

This is what I got from chrome developer tools to prepare the POST request:

```
===================================================================================
General:
 Request URL:https://www.optigura.com/product/ajax/details.php
 Request Method:POST
 Status Code:200 OK

Response Headers:
 Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
 Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
 Connection:Keep-Alive
 Content-Encoding:gzip
 Content-Length:782
 Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8

Request Headers:
 Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
 Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
 Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
 Connection:keep-alive
 Content-Length:34
 Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Cookie:OGSESSID=s1qqd0euokbfrdub9pf2efubh1; _ga=GA1.2.449310094.1501502802; _gid=GA1.2.791686763.1501502802; _gat=1; __atuvc=1%7C31; __atuvs=597f1d5241db0352000; beyable-TrackingId=499b4c5b-2939-479b-aaf0-e5cd79f078cc; aaaaaaaaa066e9a68e5654b829144016246e1a736=d5758131-71db-41e1-846d-6d719d381060.1501502805122.1501502805122.$bey$https%3a%2f%2fwww.optigura.com%2fuk%2fproduct%2fgold-standard-100-whey%2f$bey$1; aaaaaaaaa066e9a68e5654b829144016246e1a736_cs=; aaaaaaaaa066e9a68e5654b829144016246e1a736_v=1.1.0; checkloc-uk=n
 Host:www.optigura.com
 Origin:https://www.optigura.com
 Referer:https://www.optigura.com/uk/product/gold-standard-100-whey/
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
 X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Data:
opt:flavor
opt1:207
opt2:47
ip:105
=======================================================================================
```

Here is what I'm trying with:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

payload = {"opt":"flavor","opt1":"207","opt2":"47","ip":"105"}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.post("https://www.optigura.com/product/ajax/details.php", params = payload, headers = headers).text
print(response)
```

This is the original link to the webpage:
`https://www.optigura.com/uk/product/gold-standard-100-whey/`

Comment: You are not sending the values in a POST body, `params` sets the URL query parameters. Use `data` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try below request structure:

- Data to send:

  ```
  data = {'opt': 'flavor', 'opt1': '207', 'opt2': '47', 'ip': 105}
  ```
- Headers:

  ```
  headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
  ```
- URL:

  ```
  url = 'https://www.optigura.com/product/ajax/details.php'
  ```
- Also you need  to get cookies, so `requests.session()` is required:

  ```
  s = requests.session()
  r = s.get('https://www.optigura.com/uk/product/gold-standard-100-whey/')
  cookies = r.cookies
  ```

Complete request:

```
response = s.post(url, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Now you can get required piece of `HTML` as

```
print(response.json()['info2'])
```

Output:

```
'<ul class="opt2"><li class="active">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="ipr" value="1360" data-opt-sel="47" checked="checked" /> Delicious Strawberry - <span class="green">In Stock</span></label>
                </li><li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="ipr" value="1356" data-opt-sel="15"  /> Double Rich Chocolate - <span class="green">In Stock</span></label>
                </li><li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="ipr" value="1169" data-opt-sel="16"  /> Vanilla Ice Cream - <span class="green">In Stock</span></label>
                </li></ul>'
```

Then you can use `lxml` to scrape flavor values:

```
from lxml import html

flavors = response.json()['info2']
source = html.fromstring(flavors)

[print(element.replace(' - ', '').strip()) for element in source.xpath('//label/text()[2]')]
```

Output:

```
Delicious Strawberry
Double Rich Chocolate
Vanilla Ice Cream
```

Comment: Oh my god!! What an elaborative answer!! It did what I was exactly after. Sir Martijn Pieters  also suggested the same but I was not able to figured it out properly how things should be. Thanks a lot sir, Andersson. You made my day.

Answer (score 4):

You are not sending the values in a POST body, `params` sets the URL query parameters. Use `data` instead:

```
response = requests.post(
    "https://www.optigura.com/product/ajax/details.php",
    data=payload, 
    headers=headers)
```

You may need to set a referrer header (add `'Referer': 'https://www.optigura.com/uk/product/gold-standard-100-whey/'` to your headers dictionary), and use a [session object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) to capture and manage cookies (issue a GET request to  `https://www.optigura.com/uk/product/gold-standard-100-whey/` first).

With a little experimentation I noticed that the site also demands that the `X-Requested-With` header is set before it'll respond with the contents.

The following works:

```
with requests.session():
    session.get('https://www.optigura.com/uk/product/gold-standard-100-whey/')
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36',
        'Referer': 'https://www.optigura.com/uk/product/gold-standard-100-whey/',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }
    response = session.post(
        "https://www.optigura.com/product/ajax/details.php",
        data=payload, headers=headers)
```

The response comes as JSON data:

```
data = response.json()
```

Comment: Trying to cope up with what you have suggested sir Martijn Pieters. Kinda advanced level for me, though!